# No module named blog.urls

Tags: django

Recently found a django's blog

Install to own computer later

Run up appear this kind of mistake, how to solve?

```
No module named blog.urlsRequest Method: GET 
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
Django Version: 1.2.4 
Exception Type: ImportError 
Exception Value: No module named blog.urls 
Exception Location: C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35 
Python Executable: C:\Python25\python.exe 
Python Version: 2.5.1 
Python Path: ['E:\\source\\DjangoBlog\\DjangoBlog', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c7-py2.5.egg', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-2.0.9-py2.5.egg', 'E:\\source\\DjangoBlog\\DjangoBlog\\src', 'C:\\Python25', 'C:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python25\\lib', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip', 'D:\\ecliipse\\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_1.6.3.2010100513\\PySrc', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL'] 
Server time: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 15:36:58 +0800
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Python Path E:\source\DjangoBlog\DjangoBlog - DjangoBlog is directory where your project placed? Is where blog directory inside? if not try rename project directory to 'blog'

Comment: I'm under your way to try again once, or no appear or original error 

Should not file named on mistakes and still thank you.